# Deleting all "<Time>" Nodes in xDocument

Tags: c#, xml

I seem to be having trouble deleting nodes in an XDocument.

Here is me opening the file and then loading the file in an XDocument, but from here i am unsure on how to delete all the "Nodes" that are called "Time".

```
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream doc = localStorage.OpenFile(xmlFile, FileMode.Open))
{
    System.Xml.Linq.XDocument test = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(doc);                 
}
```

Here is the sample XML:

```
<Shape xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Latitude>51.262952</Latitude>
<Longitude>-0.596507</Longitude>
<Elevation>0</Elevation>
<AltitudeRef>Ellipsoid</AltitudeRef>
<Name>Route 2</Name>
<Description />
<Time xsi:nil="true" />
<Number xsi:nil="true" />
<Type>Route</Type>
<Extensions />
<LineColour>102</LineColour>
<LineOpacity>0.800000011920929</LineOpacity>
<LineWidth>5</LineWidth>
<ShapeType>Route</ShapeType>
<ShapeSegments>
  <ShapeSegment>
    <Points>
      <Point>
        <Latitude>51.262952</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-0.596507</Longitude>
        <Elevation>47.63</Elevation>
        <AltitudeRef>Ellipsoid</AltitudeRef>
        <Time>2016-01-15T11:58:48.0449337+00:00</Time>
        <Name>WP0</Name>
        <Type>Waypoint</Type>
        <Description>Depart Cumberland Avenue toward Weydown Lane</Description>
        <RestTicks>0</RestTicks>
        <DatabaseID>-1</DatabaseID>
      </Point>
      <Point>
        <Latitude>51.26366</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-0.595391</Longitude>
        <Elevation>45.71</Elevation>
        <AltitudeRef>Ellipsoid</AltitudeRef>
        <Time>2016-01-15T11:58:48.0469339+00:00</Time>
        <Name>WP1</Name>
        <Type>Waypoint</Type>
        <Description />
        <RestTicks>0</RestTicks>
        <DatabaseID>-1</DatabaseID>
      </Point>
```

I want to remove all the Nodes called "Time" and then save.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty straight forward - create a query for all descendant elements with the name `Time` and remove them:

```
test.Descendants("Time").Remove()
```

Comment: `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement> does not contain a definition for 'Remove'.`

Comment: You need to make sure you have a `using` directive for `System.Xml.Linq`.